# Segues where a view replaces another

Tags: swift, ios8, segue

I'm planning a game app where a series of views are presented, one after the other, sequentially, in a loop.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the segue I should use for this (using the storyboard). It seems to me, that using the 'show' segue will result in a stack of views. In my app, you never go back from where you came, so does that mean that I could end up with dozens of views, one on top of each other?

Is there a way so that once you go into a segue, one view replaces the previous view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you are not going to be able to do this with Storyboard segues as the "Replace" segue is only for SplitViewController (which sounds like wouldn't be right for what you are trying to do). Instead handle transitions through code. Have a base navigation controller and keep setting the new view controllers as the navigation controller's root view controller

Comment: Not even with a 'Custom' segue? So I would have to do it the old fashion way with a bunch of XIBs (one per view)?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with custom segues but I at least haven't seen them used in the way you have described. Not sure if it is possible or not